# How to create Redis Transaction in Go using go-redis/redis package?

Tags: go, transactions, redis

I want to execute multiple redis commmand with transaction using `MULTI` and `EXEC`, so I can `DISCARD` it if something bad happens.

I've looking for the example of how to do redis transaction using
[go-redis/redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) package and found nothing.

And I also look into the documentation [here](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5) and I got nothing related to how to do redis transaction [like this for example](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) using that package. Or maybe I missing something from the documentation because yeah you know that godoc is only explain every function in package mostly using one liner.

Even though I found some example to do redis transaction using other Go Redis library, I won't modify my programs to use another library since the effort will be much larger to port whole application using another library.

Can anyone help me to do that using go-redis/redis package?

Comment: Transactions in that package are call [Tx](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5#Tx)

Comment: i know that. but how to create tx object?
i didn't find any function that return tx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get a [`Tx`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5#Tx) value for a transaction when you use [`Client.Watch`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5#Client.Watch)

```
err := client.Watch(func(tx *redis.Tx) error {
    n, err := tx.Get(key).Int64()
    if err != nil && err != redis.Nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = tx.Pipelined(func(pipe *redis.Pipeline) error {
        pipe.Set(key, strconv.FormatInt(n+1, 10), 0)
        return nil
    })
    return err
}, key)
```

Comment: wow i didn't see that in the docs. 
Tx is a param in anonymous function inside `Watch` function. that's why i miss it.
thanks man.

Comment: the code in this answer will generate next redis commands: ```WATCH key GET key SET key UNWATCH``` which is not how transactions are explained on redis website https://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas . In order to wrap SET with ```MULTI / EXEC```, use ```tx.TxPipelined``` instead of ```tx.Pipelined```.

Answer (score 14):

You can find an example how to create a Redis transaction [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#example-Client-TxPipeline):

Code:

```
pipe := rdb.TxPipeline()

incr := pipe.Incr("tx_pipeline_counter")
pipe.Expire("tx_pipeline_counter", time.Hour)

// Execute
//
//     MULTI
//     INCR pipeline_counter
//     EXPIRE pipeline_counts 3600
//     EXEC
//
// using one rdb-server roundtrip.
_, err := pipe.Exec()
fmt.Println(incr.Val(), err)
```

Output:

```
1 <nil>
```

And if you prefer to use the [watch](https://redis.io/commands/watch) (optimistic locking)
You can see an example [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Client.Watch)

Code:

```
const routineCount = 100

// Transactionally increments key using GET and SET commands.
increment := func(key string) error {
    txf := func(tx *redis.Tx) error {
        // get current value or zero
        n, err := tx.Get(key).Int()
        if err != nil && err != redis.Nil {
            return err
        }

        // actual opperation (local in optimistic lock)
        n++

        // runs only if the watched keys remain unchanged
        _, err = tx.TxPipelined(func(pipe redis.Pipeliner) error {
            // pipe handles the error case
            pipe.Set(key, n, 0)
            return nil
        })
        return err
    }

    for retries := routineCount; retries > 0; retries-- {
        err := rdb.Watch(txf, key)
        if err != redis.TxFailedErr {
            return err
        }
        // optimistic lock lost
    }
    return errors.New("increment reached maximum number of retries")
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(routineCount)
for i := 0; i < routineCount; i++ {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        if err := increment("counter3"); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("increment error:", err)
        }
    }()
}
wg.Wait()

n, err := rdb.Get("counter3").Int()
fmt.Println("ended with", n, err)
```

Output:

```
ended with 100 <nil>
```